# De Moivre's theorem question regarding $(\cos \theta + i \sin\theta)^3$

Tags: complex-numbers

[image: Question]

Can someone double check that the question in (a) (ii) is wrong, because I got
$\cos 3 \theta = 4 \cos^3 \theta -3 \cos \theta $ after I compared the real parts, and I got $\sin 3 \theta = 3 \sin \theta -4 \sin^3 \theta $ after comparing imaginary parts.

However, I need to check if the given (a)(ii) is right or is my working right, as I am stuck on (b) and (c).

Using my results, for (b), I tried doing

$\frac{\sin3\theta-\sin\theta}{\cos3\theta+\cos\theta}$=$\frac{2 \sin\theta-4\sin ^3\theta}{4\cos^3\theta-2\cos\theta}$ which wouldn't get me anywhere near $tan \theta$. Please advise.

And would anyone be able to suggest how I attempt part (c) as well?

Also, sorry in advance for any wrong title or tags (trying to improve on it!)

Comment: Words such as *question* are uninformative in titles. Please [edit] the title so that it better describes the specifics of your question. Do not hesitate to make it longer or include a formula if needed. More tips [here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). *(autocomment)*

Comment: Thx @Normal, would it be better now?

Comment: Your title now is ok

Comment: You are right. It is a misprint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's obvious that the formula is miswritten. If you set $\theta = \pi/6$ you'll see:

$$\cos 3\theta = \cos \pi/2 = 0 \ne 4 \cos 3\theta - 3\cos \theta = 4\cos \pi/2 - 3\cos \pi/6 = -3\cos\pi/6$$

It look's like the printer had problems with superscripts, I too get the same result as you. So where they intend $\cos^3\theta$ they printed $\cos 3\theta$. Unfortunately the printing error results in ambiguity as they sometimes actually means $\cos 3\theta$.

The (b) depends on the corrected formulas from (a) and second seems OK (here they actually means $\sin 3\theta$ and $\cos 3\theta$):

$${2\sin \theta - 4\sin^3 \theta\over 4\cos^3\theta - 2\cos\theta} = {\sin\theta\over\cos\theta}{1-2\sin^2\theta\over 2\cos^2\theta-1} = {1-2\sin^2\theta\over2(1-\sin^2\theta)-1}\tan \theta = {1-2\sin^2\theta\over1-2\sin^2\theta}\tan \theta$$

For (c) you'll use the formulas formulas you found in (a) for $\sin 3\theta$ and $\cos 3\theta$ and insert in $\tan 3\theta = {\sin3\theta \over \cos 3\theta}$.

Comment: Thanks @skyking, but doesn't (b) depends on the wrong formula in (a)?

Comment: It appears that sometimes they mean $\cos 3\theta$, and sometimes they mean $\cos^3 \theta$

Answer (score 1):

You are right. On the other hand:

$\frac{sin3\theta-sin\theta}{cos3\theta+cos\theta}=\frac{2 sin\theta-4sin ^3\theta}{4cos^3\theta-2cos\theta}=\frac{2\sin\theta(1-2\sin^2\theta)}{2\cos\theta(2\cos^2\theta-1)}=\tan\theta\frac{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta}=\tan\theta$

For the third one, note that

$\sin 3\theta=3\sin\theta-4\sin^3\theta=1-4(1/3)^3=1-4/27=23/27$. Let $a=23/27$

Also, note

$\begin{eqnarray}
2\cos^3 3\theta-\cos3\theta&=&\cos3\theta(2\cos^23\theta-1)\\
&=&\cos3\theta(cos^23\theta-\sin^23\theta)\\
&=&\cos3\theta(\cos^23\theta-a^2)
\end{eqnarray}$

As $\sin\theta=1/3$, then $\cos3\theta\neq0$. Thus $2\cos^23\theta-1=\cos^23\theta-a^2$, from which $\cos^23\theta=1-a^2$.

Finally, $\tan^23\theta=\dfrac{\sin^23\theta}{\cos^23\theta}=\dfrac{a^2}{1-a^2}$.